# active hashを使用し、選択された商品によって金額の表示を行いたい

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

初めまして、ruby,ruby on rails, JavaScript初学者です。

掲題の件飲食店の予約サイトを作成しているのですが、active hashを使用し、選択されたコース料理によって一人当たりの費用が出るように実装を行いたいです。

試したこと
active hashを用いたモデル内に:nameと:priceを作成した。
→プルダウン表示は可能ですが、連動させることができませんでした。

gyazoの画像も添付させていただきます。
https://gyazo.com/5fa62942e8e1a135e738535a51bcb9de

不足情報等がございましたら、ご質問いただけると幸いです。
どうぞ宜しくお願い致します。

---

models/menu.rb

```
class Menu < ActiveHash::Base
  self.data = [
  { id: 1, name: '季節のおまかせコース', price: '8,800'},
  { id: 2, name: '海鮮鍋セットコース', price: '10,800'},
  { id: 3, name: '季節のおまかせコース + 2時間飲み放題', price: '12,800'},
  { id: 4, name: '海鮮鍋セットコース + 2時間飲み放題', price: '15,000'}
  ]

  include ActiveHash::Associations
  has_many :reservations
end
```

views/reservation.html.erb

```
<h1><%= link_to '予約フォーム', root_path, class:'reservation-form'%></h1>
<%= form_with model: @reservation, url: new_reservation_path, method: :get, class: 'reservation', local: true do |f| %>

    <div class="reservation-price">
      <h2>コース選択</h2>

      <div calss="reservation-date">
        <%= f.label :日付を選択, class: 'label'%><br />
        <%= f.date_field :date, class: 'date' %>
      </div>

      <div class="reservation-time">
        <%= f.label :時間を選択, class: 'label' %><br />
        <%= f.time_field :time, class: 'time'%>
      </div>

      <div class="reservation-people">
        <%= f.label :人数%><br />
        <%= f.number_field :people, class: 'people'%>人
      </div>

      <%# 該当箇所 %>
      <div class="menu">
        コース<br />
        <%= f.collection_select(:menu_id, Menu.all, :id, :name, {})%>
      </div>
      
      <div class="person-price">
        <span>1人当たりのお支払い</span><br />
        <span>
        <span></span>円 
        </span>
      </div>
      <%# /該当箇所 %>

      <div class="total-price">
        <span>合計金額</span><br />
        <span>
        <span></span>円
        </span>
      </div>

      <div class="reservation-remark">
        <%= f.label :その他%><br />
        <%= f.text_area :remark, placeholder:"嫌いな食べ物など",class: 'remark'%>
      </div>

    <div>
      <%= f.submit "予約する"%> <br />
    </div>

  <div class="reservation-btn">
    <%= link_to '戻る', root_path, class:'reservation-form'%> 
  </div>
  
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

予約ボタンを押す前にプルダウンを変更した際に金額を表示するってことでいいんですよね？

プルダウンから予約内容を変更しただけではサーバーへの通信は発生せず
サーバーサイドだけでもってるデータは利用できません

予約する submit をクリックしてはじめてサーバーへの通信が起きて
ページ遷移によってサーバーサイドデータを利用することができます

---

実現方法は大きく以下２つあります

プルダウンを変更するたびにページ遷移を起こして
サーバーサイドで金額を埋めたページを生成する

クライアントサイドでプルダウン変更時に金額部分のHTMLを動的に変更する

---

後者の方法が自然だと思うんですが price をクライアントと共有するために
option tag にうめこむなり javascript 内でテーブルをもつ必要があります

たとえば collection_select じゃなく
f.select で以下のように option タグに price を埋め込みます

```
<%= f.select :menu_id, (Menu.all.map {|m| [m.name, m.id, {'data-price' => m.price }]}), {}, {id: 'menu_select'} %>
```

これで以下のようなHTMLが生成されます

```
<select id="menu_select">
<option value="1" data-price="8800">季節のおまかせコース</option>
<option value="2" data-price="10800">海鮮鍋セットコース</option>
<option value="3" data-price="12800">季節のおまかせコース + 2時間飲み放題</option>
<option value="4" data-price="15000">海鮮鍋セットコース + 2時間飲み放題</option>
</select>
```

JS側はたとえばこんな感じ

```js
// プルダウンを変更するたびにこの処理が呼ばれる
$('#menu_select').on('change', () => {
  
  // 選択されたオプションに埋め込まれた price を取得
  const price = $('#menu_select > option:selected').data('price');
  
  // total_price のIDのついた span の中に金額文字列をセットする
  $('#total_price').text(price);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="menu_select">
<option value="1" data-price="8800">季節のおまかせコース</option>
<option value="2" data-price="10800">海鮮鍋セットコース</option>
<option value="3" data-price="12800">季節のおまかせコース + 2時間飲み放題</option>
<option value="4" data-price="15000">海鮮鍋セットコース + 2時間飲み放題</option>
</select>

<div class="total-price">
  <span>合計金額</span><br />
  <span id="total_price"></span>円
  </span>
</div>
```

---

pure javascript 版です

```js
const menu_select = document.getElementById("menu_select")
menu_select.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
  const selected_index = menu_select.selectedIndex;
    const selected_option = menu_select.options[selected_index];
  const price = selected_option.getAttribute("data-price");
  document.getElementById("total_price").innerHTML = price;
});
```

```html
 <select id="menu_select">
    <option value="1" data-price="8800">季節のおまかせコース</option>
    <option value="2" data-price="10800">海鮮鍋セットコース</option>
    <option value="3" data-price="12800">季節のおまかせコース + 2時間飲み放題</option>
    <option value="4" data-price="15000">海鮮鍋セットコース + 2時間飲み放題</option>
    </select>

    <div class="total-price">
      <span>合計金額</span><br />
      <span id="total_price"></span>円
      </span>
    </div>
```

Comment: 様

ご返信ありがとうございます。
いただいた内容をJAVAに入力したところ
”Uncaught TypeError: "#menu_select".on is not a function”
と出てしまいまして、＄があることが原因かと思い、消してみたところ
”Uncaught TypeError: "#menu_select".on is not a function”と出てしまいました。

検証を行いidを確認致しましたが、問題なさそうです。
https://gyazo.com/3449419ac12ce67c081f570a7d85747a

エラーメッセージ
https://gyazo.com/9ca07e4907ca801d2b997c9a3dfc8397

他に考えられる原因をご教示いただけないでしょうか。
どうぞ宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: jquery がはいってないからですね。pure javascript でも同じことはかけると思いますが自分は jquery しかかけないのですみません。<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js" integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>　を javascript の前にはさめば jquery 自体は使えると思います。本当は gem で jquery-rails とか入れたほうが Rails 流ではありますけど

Comment: 様 たびたび丁寧なご返信ありがとうございます。 <script src="code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js" integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> ビューファイルに以下のような形で記述する形でよろしいのでしょうか。 div class="menu"> コース<br /> <script src="code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js" integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> <%= f.select :menu_id, (Menu.all.map {|m| [m.name, m.id, {'data-price' => m.price }]}), {}, {id: 'menu_select'} %> </div>

Comment: 様
上記記述したところ以下の添付gyazoのエラーが出ました。 gyazo.com/9c6c67a49fcd436e81bbaa888c1853db その後、上記記述を削除後にjquery-railsをGemfile最下部に記述し、bundle install→rails を行いページリロードを行ったところ以下のエラーとなってしました。 gyazo.com/94b4c01893334bbde0b134a89087a41d 私のscriptから始まる記述位置が異なっているかと思うのですが、いかがでしょうか –

Comment: 質問の本題からずれててあまりコメントで長いソースのやりとりするのもあれなので Rails での jquery の使い方とかで別質問に分けたほうがいいかと思います。jquery を使うのはあくまで１つの方法で自分がなれてないだけで pure javascript でも可能です。
エラーを見たところ web packer を使ってるみたいで新しい Rails は javascript の扱いが結構変わってるので質問する際バージョンも記載したほうがいいです

Comment: @ chico様

こんにちは、大変失礼いたしました。別質問にて投稿させていただきます。
初めての質問で、回答しづらい内容だったかと思いますが、ご丁寧にご回答いただけて大変嬉しく思っております！

本当にありがとうございました！

Comment: 自分は webpacker を使った jqeury の導入をしたことがないので力になれずすみません。一応 jquery を使わない書き方も追記しておきました。ただDOM（HTML要素）をいじるならjqueryを覚えたほうが短くかけると思います

Comment: @chico様

遅くなり申し訳ございません。
無事に表示させることができました。

質問までにかなりの時間1人で悩んでおりましたので、大変助かりました。
本当にありがとうございました。